# Solutions for dynamic WCF client proxy in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, wcf-client

I currently need to access WCF services from within Silverlight (3.0) application, but I need it dynamic.
What I have access to : the service interfaces (ServiceContracts) and data definitions (DataContracts).
What I need : runtime generated/created WCF client proxy.

Have some solutions?

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic proxy? Are you just looking to dynamically set the endpoint of the proxy?

Comment: Well, I need the whole proxy to be dynamic so I can get rid of the design-time generated proxies.

Comment: To answer the "why" question: I have a dynamic WCF host exposing services provided at runtime, I have a client platform running plug-ins calling the services through the client platform, I want to share only the service descriptions, I plan sharing these same service descriptions on both .Net clients and Silverlight clients. I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones : thanks for the tags revision.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [WCF Dynamic Proxy Sample Project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=netfxsamples&DownloadId=3939)

Comment: Thanks.
I already had a look at this, but this is not easy to port to Silverlight.  
I'm looking for a Silverlight-ready solution... If there is any at the moment :)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link! That helped me with a similar problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

I found this "old" post (September 16, 2008).
But I could not make it run properly under Silverlight 3.0 (didn't try with previous versions of Silverlight).

[WorkSight Blog » Blog Archive » A Dynamic WCF Client Proxy in Silverlight](http://worksightblog.com/?p=73)

Let us know if any of you manages to make it work! :)

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is if you follow the procedure of client access described in [Understanding WCF Services In Silverlight 2](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/Understanding-WCF-Services-in-Silverlight-2), you should be able to choose which service to access at runtime, because you don't need to create proxy at client side.

**A snippet from this article:**

> Now we may turn our attention to the
>   client application.  To begin, let me
>   start off by reminding everyone that
>   you shouldn't ever use "Add Service
>   Reference" in Visual Studio for
>   magical service client creation.  The
>   code is incredibly verbose, hard to
>   manageable, edits are prone to being
>   overwritten, and it's almost always
>   used as an excuse to not actually
>   learn WCF.
>
> As I've mentioned many times already,
>   WCF relies on the concept of the ABC. 
>   For both
>   .NET and Silverlight, you merge an
>   address and a binding with a contract
>   in a channel factory to create a
>   channel.  This isn't just fancy
>   conceptual architect speak, this is
>   exactly what your code would look like
>   (the sign of really good
>   architecture!)  Below is the .NET
>   version of what I mean:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1003/Person.svc");
IPersonService personService = new ChannelFactory<IPersonService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();

Person person = personService.GetPersonData("F488D20B-FC27-4631-9FB9-83AF616AB5A6");
```

Comment: As he said, this is "the .NET version of". Silverlight do only support async service calls and most services do not provide interface for async calls (and IMO they should'nt). Starting at that point, things go lot more tricky.

Comment: What I expect is something more like what K.Kozmic does in .Net : see
 http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/08/09/making-asynchronous-wcf-calls-without-svcutil.aspx